# Assigning keyboard shortcut to get path of selected item in windows explorer

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, explorer, windows-shell

I don't know if this is even possible, but how can I bind some key combination to a (C#)program, so that when that keyboard shortcut is pressed with some file selected in windows explorer, it calls specific function with path of that file as a parameter.

Or can I assign some keyboard shortcut so that windows explorer opens selected file in my program(that way I could pass the path to already running instance)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your program to run as a shell extension which would add an item for your program to the right-click menu in windows explorer, but apparently coding shell extensions in C# is a [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194572/windows-shell-extension-with-c) [idea](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Shell_Extensions).

As an alternative, with a little work [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can do this.  [Here's](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic9149.html) a sample script that renames the selected file in Windows Explorer when a certain keyboard combination is pressed.  You could modify it to run your C# program and pass the selected filename.

Comment: Thanks!
I altough came up with a simpler method already. When global hotkey is pressed, I emulate CTRL+C shortcut, that way I get paths of the selected files to clipboard, and after that I can read them from there. 
The are few problems though, but I think I can overcome those somehow(file gets copied multiple times(and the function runs more than once), maybe that can be solved with timer or something...)