# C# And windows explorer context menu?

Tags: c#, contextmenu, windows-explorer

I have an idea for a little C# program, where I want to be able to right click on a file in windows explorer and somehow 'tag' that file.  Subsequent right clicks would show it's tagged state.

Bottom line is that I need to be able to right click on a file, see a custom menu item and perform a custom action as well as visualize some info.

Never having done this, I'm not even sure where to start... :)

Any good example out there?  Things I should read up on?  Links?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make a context menu in C#, but you shouldn't. Doing so would require the CLR to be loaded into every process that shows an Open/Save dialog!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is **Shell Extensions**. For more information, see [Windows shell extension with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194572/windows-shell-extension-with-c) or [Creating a shell extension with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dateparser.aspx).