# How to add templates to the explorer's "new" panel using C# code

Tags: c#, templates, addition

I want to use C# code to add templates to the explorer's "new" panel.

What I mean is:
[Explorer.exe "new" panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh0ZV.jpg)

Is there any way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ´Is there any way to do that?´ > Yes, most probably. What have you tried ?

Comment: Well, I figured it's most likely to be in the registry. I was learning about registry locations a bit recently.. And how to edit the registry with C# code. However, I have no idea how to start off with this. There's no information about the New panel out there.

Comment: May be helpful: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701306/c-sharp-and-windows-explorer-context-menu

Comment: No, It doesn't have anything to do with what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it [manually](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu) so doing it in C# is just a matter of automation. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144101(VS.85).aspx#new