# Context Shell Menus - Get identifier on click

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-shell

I have created a context shell menu for / on `.txt` files.

Its 'action' is similar to that of 'Edit with notepad' option.

I am able to open 'notepad' on clicking the menu using this code -

```
subKey.SetValue("", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");

 //subKey is the newly created sub key - The key creation part works fine.
```

How will I be able to use a feature similar to that of the 'Edit with notepad' feature? Or is it at least possible to get the name of the '.txt' file on which this event was triggered?

**Note:** By 'Edit with notepad', I mean viewing the selected file's contents in notepad.

Comment: As far as I know you need to create an "explorer extension" to be able to create custom context menus.

Comment: I am able to create menus or 'menu items' (sorry , I mean the 'Open with..' kind) by accessing the registry, and am able to open notepad, but as a 'Create New File' type.

Comment: How do you create the menu?

Comment: Please check this out, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194572/windows-shell-extension-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell (`explorer.exe`) will substitute `%1` with the file name. So you basically write:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\openwithnotepad]
@="Open with &Notepad"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\openwithnotepad\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe\" \"%1\""
```

The file name will be passed to `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` as a command line argument. For example if you open `D:\blah.txt`, then notepad will receive `D:\blah.txt` as the first argument.

In C#, you basically use either [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) or [`args` in `Main`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the file path.

An example:

```
string[] commandLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
string fileToOpen = null;
if (commandLineArgs.Length > 1)
{
    if (File.Exists(commandLineArgs[1]))
    {
        fileToOpen = commandLineArgs[1];
    }
}
if (fileToOpen == null)
{
    // new file
}
else
{
    MyEditor.OpenFile(fileToOpen);
}
```

Comment: I ran the registry in 'Administrator mode'. The key is being created, but I am unable to see the same on right clicking a .txt file.

Comment: Upon doing that, it says that the keys have been successfully added to the registry. Still, I don't see the `openwithnotepad` option.

Comment: Try manually editing the default value of `HKCR\txtfile\shell\openwithnotepad\command` to `"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" "%1"`.

Comment: That is the value that is currently set.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28992/discussion-between-user2053912-and-alvin-wong)