# how to chose folder by mouse event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I just started writing my application which will help us to protect a folder with a password, when we open the menu on folders, we will see a "Create Password" entry. You can see this on the screen.

[image: option "create password"]

My question is: How can I get information abouth which folder the user has choosen, it's a WPF application and I can find nothing. Thanks for help and sorry for my language ;)

Comment: Seems like you've written a shell extension for the windows explorer right click menu, how does that relate to a C# WPF application oO? How did you implement /register that shell extension?

Comment: i wrote project in wpf application which let us create password on folder, but i don't know how to get information which folder user has choosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus) about the [SharpShell](http://sharpshell.codeplex.com/) project, it looks like with it you would use the `SelectedItemPaths` property. [Windows Shell Extensions in .NET](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169474&seqNum=2) says:

> The purpose of the Initialize method is to get information about the **selected items** in the shell and save that information for later calls. The m_dataObject and m_hDrop fields are used to store this information in the COM object between calls.

*(emphasis added)*

But [conventional wisdom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194572/windows-shell-extension-with-c-sharp) and [guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089(v=vs.85).aspx) is that you shouldn't, in general, write shell extensions in managed code.

> **Microsoft recommends against writing managed in-process extensions to Windows Explorer or Windows Internet Explorer and does not consider them a supported scenario.**

*(emphasis theirs)*

They do give some examples where it is OK.

Comment: So should i write it again but in .net application?

Comment: Your question is tagged with C# and WPF.  C# is a .NET language, WPF is the UI Framework that you are implementing with.  The direction from MS is to use C++ or some other non-managed language.  Updated the answer.