# How can i make shell context menus on file explorer to resize images in directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have windows 10.

It take some time until i see a messageBox say it was registered not sure why it's taking time. And after it nothing happen i don't see the context menus when doing mouse right click in the file explorer. One of the menus is Resize and when i click on it select it, it should run a method in the program that will resize all the images in the current directory i'm in the file explorer.

But even if it was working on windows 8 almost a year ago the resize action was taking lot of time, not sure why.

This is the code of Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
namespace SimpleContextMenu
{
    static class Program
    {
        // file type to register
        const string FileType = "bitmapfile";//"jpegfile";

        // context menu name in the registry
        const string KeyName = "Simple Context Menu";
        const string KeyName1 = "Simple Context Menu1";

        // context menu text
        const string MenuText = "Copy to Grayscale";
        const string MenuText1 = "Resize all images";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
            // process register or unregister commands
            if (!ProcessCommand(args))
            {
                string action = args[0];
                MessageBox.Show(action);
                string fileName = args[1];

                if (action == "Copy")
                {
                    // invoked from shell, process the selected file
                    CopyGrayscaleImage(fileName);
                }
                else if (action == "Resize")
                {
                    string FilePath = Path.Combine(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName),
                    string.Format("{0} (resized){1}",
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
                    Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
                    MessageBox.Show(FilePath);
                    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(ResizeImages(FilePath, 100, 100));
                    bmp1.Save(FilePath);
                    bmp1.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Process command line actions (register or unregister).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Command line arguments.</param>
        /// <returns>True if processed an action in the command line.</returns>
        static bool ProcessCommand(string[] args)
        {
            // register
            if (args.Length == 0 || string.Compare(args[0], "-register", true) == 0)
            {
                // full path to self, %L is placeholder for selected file
                string menuCommand = string.Format("\"{0}\" Copy \"%L\"", Application.ExecutablePath);

                // register the context menu
                FileShellExtension.Register(Program.FileType,
                    Program.KeyName, Program.MenuText,
                    menuCommand);

                string menuCommand1 = string.Format("\"{0}\" Resize \"%L\"", Application.ExecutablePath);

                FileShellExtension.Register(Program.FileType,
                    Program.KeyName1, Program.MenuText1,
                    menuCommand1);

                MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
                    "The {0} shell extension was registered.",
                    Program.KeyName), Program.KeyName);

                return true;
            }

            // unregister       
            if (string.Compare(args[0], "-unregister", true) == 0)
            {
                // unregister the context menu
                FileShellExtension.Unregister(Program.FileType, Program.KeyName);

                MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
                    "The {0} shell extension was unregistered.",
                    Program.KeyName), Program.KeyName);

                return true;
            }

            // command line did not contain an action
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Make a grayscale copy of the image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">Full path to the image to copy.</param>
        static void CopyGrayscaleImage(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                // full path to the grayscale copy
                string grayFilePath = Path.Combine(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath),
                    string.Format("{0} (grayscale){1}",
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath),
                    Path.GetExtension(filePath)));

                // using calls Dispose on the objects, important 
                // so the file is not locked when the app terminates
                using (Image image = new Bitmap(filePath))
                using (Bitmap grayImage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height))
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(grayImage))
                {
                    // setup grayscale matrix
                    ImageAttributes attr = new ImageAttributes();
                    attr.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{   
                        new float[]{0.3086F,0.3086F,0.3086F,0,0},
                        new float[]{0.6094F,0.6094F,0.6094F,0,0},
                        new float[]{0.082F,0.082F,0.082F,0,0},
                        new float[]{0,0,0,1,0,0},
                        new float[]{0,0,0,0,1,0},
                        new float[]{0,0,0,0,0,1}}));

                    // create the grayscale image
                    g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                        0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);

                    // save to the file system
                    grayImage.Save(grayFilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    // success
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Copied grayscale image {0}", grayFilePath), Program.KeyName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message), Program.KeyName);
                return;
            }
        }

        private static Bitmap ResizeImages(String filename, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            using (Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(filename))
            {
                //Caluate new Size
                int newWidth = originalImage.Width;
                int newHeight = originalImage.Height;
                double aspectRatio = (double)originalImage.Width / (double)originalImage.Height;
                if (aspectRatio <= 1 && originalImage.Width > maxWidth)
                {
                    newWidth = maxWidth;
                    newHeight = (int)Math.Round(newWidth / aspectRatio);
                }
                else if (aspectRatio > 1 && originalImage.Height > maxHeight)
                {
                    newHeight = maxHeight;
                    newWidth = (int)Math.Round(newHeight * aspectRatio);
                }
                if (newWidth >= 0 && newHeight >= 0)
                {
                    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                    {
                        //--Quality Settings Adjust to fit your application
                        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
                        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                        g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
                        return newImage;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the FileShellExtension.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace SimpleContextMenu
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Register and unregister simple shell context menus.
    /// </summary>
    static class FileShellExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Register a simple shell context menu.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileType">The file type to register.</param>
        /// <param name="shellKeyName">Name that appears in the registry.</param>
        /// <param name="menuText">Text that appears in the context menu.</param>
        /// <param name="menuCommand">Command line that is executed.</param>
        public static void Register(
            string fileType, string shellKeyName,
            string menuText, string menuCommand)
        {
            Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(shellKeyName) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuText) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuCommand));

            // create full path to registry location
            string regPath = string.Format(@"{0}\shell\{1}", fileType, shellKeyName);

            // add context menu to the registry
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(regPath))
            {
                key.SetValue(null, menuText);
            }

            // add command that is invoked to the registry
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(
                string.Format(@"{0}\command", regPath)))
            {
                key.SetValue(null, menuCommand);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unregister a simple shell context menu.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileType">The file type to unregister.</param>
        /// <param name="shellKeyName">Name that was registered in the registry.</param>
        public static void Unregister(string fileType, string shellKeyName)
        {
            Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(shellKeyName));

            // full path to the registry location           
            string regPath = string.Format(@"{0}\shell\{1}", fileType, shellKeyName);

            // remove context menu from the registry
            Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKeyTree(regPath);
        }
    }

}
```

I know that the siggestion is not to use/touch the registry but i'm trying to find a easy way to resize images in a directory something easy interface to the user and the only way to add a context menu to the file explorer already existing menu is by register to the registry.

I'm trying to use sharpshel library now but not sure how to work with it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using SharpShell.Attributes;
using SharpShellContextMenu;
using SharpShell.SharpContextMenu;

namespace SharpShellContextMenu
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        [ComVisible(true)]
        [COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.ClassOfExtension, ".jpg")]
        public class CountLinesExtension : SharpContextMenu
        {
            protected override bool CanShowMenu()
            {
                return true;
            }

            protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
            {
                //  Create the menu strip.
                var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();

                //  Create a 'count lines' item.
                var itemCountLines = new ToolStripMenuItem
                {
                    Text = "Resize Images",
                    //Image = Properties.Resources.CountLines
                };

                //  When we click, we'll count the lines.
                itemCountLines.Click += (sender, args) => CountLines();

                //  Add the item to the context menu.
                menu.Items.Add(itemCountLines);

                //  Return the menu.
                return menu;
            }

            private void CountLines()
            {
                // do the work
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

How do i call it use it in the constructor ?

Comment: [Windows shell extension with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194572/windows-shell-extension-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing extensions for the Windows Explorer is cumbersome and errorprone work. The project SharpShell makes it easy for .net developers to integrate into the Explorer. Have a look at https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell.

Enabling an action for the context menu is done in this manner (extract from the tutorial):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.ClassOfExtension, ".txt")]
public class CountLinesExtension : SharpContextMenu
{        
    protected override bool CanShowMenu()
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
    {
        //  Create the menu strip.
        var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();

        //  Create a 'count lines' item.
        var itemCountLines = new ToolStripMenuItem
        {
            Text = "Count Lines...",
            Image = Properties.Resources.CountLines
        };

        //  When we click, we'll count the lines.
        itemCountLines.Click += (sender, args) => CountLines();

        //  Add the item to the context menu.
        menu.Items.Add(itemCountLines);

        //  Return the menu.
        return menu;
    }

    private void CountLines()
    {
        // do the work
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i use it ? Tried it now with a new project updated my question with the form1 code. But i'm not sure how to call/use it in the constructor ?

Comment: @TheLostLostit - here is a step by step tutorial by the author http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus

Comment: I saw the example but i can't figure out how to access the method CreateMenu and CountLines. I looked at the example step by step i can't figure out how to call it from the constructor.